# KineticJS How to listen to image drop from file explorer ?

Tags: image, drag-and-drop, kineticjs

I'm using kineticjs v4.5.1

I'm looking for a way to add image to my canvas from a system drag'n'drop.

I've tried to add an event listener to my container :

```
jQuery('#container').on('drop',Actions.dropImage);
```

but the event is not fired, neither with :

```
App.canvas = document.getElementById('container');
App.canvas.addEventListener('drop',Actions.dropImage);
```

**Nota : theses codes sample are working with a "regular" canvas, I'm trying here to use it with kineticJS**

**Nota 2 : I've seen this issue : [kineticjs drag and drop image from dom into canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271450/kineticjs-drag-and-drop-image-from-dom-into-canvas), but i want to do it on a drag n drop from a file explorer**

Am'I doing something wrong ?

Cheers

Comment: Can't answer my own question, but I finally found the problem, I was missing to prevent the dragover event :

`    jQuery('#wydiwyg').on('dragover',function(event){event.preventDefault();});
    jQuery('#wydiwyg').on('drop',Actions.dropImage);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem, I was missing to prevent the dragover event :

```
jQuery('#wydiwyg').on('dragover',function(event){event.preventDefault();}); 
jQuery('#wydiwyg').on('drop',Actions.dropImage);
```